# Formula for the volume of solid [Zorich's book]

Tags: definite-integrals, volume

I was reading Zorich's about application of integral and come across the following. I would be very grateful if someone can answer my question.

> We shall now prove a sufficient condition for an additive interval
> function to be generated by an integral, one that will be useful in
> what follows.
>
> **Proposition 1.** *Suppose the additive function $I(\alpha,\beta)$ defined for points $\alpha,\beta$ of a closed interval $[a,b]$ is such
> that there exists a function $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ connected with
> $I$ as follows: the relation
> $$\inf_{[\alpha,\beta]}f(x)(\beta-\alpha)\leq I(\alpha,\beta)\leq
>  \sup_{[\alpha,\beta]}f(x)(\beta-\alpha)$$ holds for any closed
> interval $[\alpha,\beta]$ such that $a\leq \alpha\leq \beta\leq b$.
> Then $$I(a,b)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx.$$*

[image]

Then the author uses that proposition in order to find the volume of a solid of revolution.

> Now suppose the curvilinear trapezoid shown in Fig. 6.2 is revolved
> about the closed interval $[a,b]$. Let us determine the volume of the
> solid that results. We denote by $V(\alpha,\beta)$ the volume of the
> solid obtained by revolving the curvilinear trapezoid $\alpha
>  f(\alpha)f(\beta)\beta$ (see Fig.6.2) corresponding to the closed
> interval $[\alpha,\beta]\subset [a,b].$
>
> According to our ideas about volume the following relations must hold:
> if $a\leq \alpha<\beta<\gamma\leq b,$ then
> $$V(\alpha,\gamma)=V(\alpha,\beta)+V(\beta,\gamma)$$ and $$\pi\left(
>  \inf_{[\alpha,\beta]}f(x)\right)^2(\beta-\alpha)\leq
>  V(\alpha,\beta)\leq \pi\left(
>  \sup_{[\alpha,\beta]}f(x)\right)^2(\beta-\alpha).$$ In this last
> relation we have estimated the volume $V(\alpha,\beta)$ by the volumes
> inscribed and circumscribed cylinders and used the formula for the
> volume of a cylinder.
>
> Then by Proposition 1 $$V(a,b)=\pi \int_a^b f^2(x)dx.$$

The last line bothers me a lot. To be honest I do not see how he applies Proposition 1. In order to apply Proposition 1 inequality should be $$
 \inf_{[\alpha,\beta]}(\pi f^2(x))(\beta-\alpha)\leq
 V(\alpha,\beta)\leq \inf_{[\alpha,\beta]}(\pi f^2(x))(\beta-\alpha),$$ right? Can anyone explain to me that moment please?

Comment: if $f\ge 0$, the last inequality is just identical with the inequality in proposition. So $f$ may be assumed to be positive?

Comment: @stephenkk, that makes sense! However, the author does not make any remark about positivity of function $f$. Am I right that my remark makes sense in this context? I mean in order to apply Proposition 1 we need to have the inequality which I mentioned.

Comment: Note that $f$ is just the revolution radius which must be non-negative. The right hand side of your last inequality should be sup instead of inf.